How to format string date for AWS glue crawler/data frame to correctly identify as date field?
I have some json data (sample below). aws glue crawler reads this data and creates a glue catalog database with table , and sets the date field as a string field . is there a way , i can format date in my json file such that crawler can identify this as a date field ? I plan to read this data into dynamic frame via aws glue etl and push it to a sql database , where I want to save it as a date field , so that it is easy to query and do comparisons on the date field. example of script below.
can i convert the string date field to rds date field in spark data frame?
myscript.py
data=gluecontext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="sample", table_name="table" ...

data_frame=data.toDF()

//convert the string field to date field in the spark data frame

{"id": "abc", .... date="2024-07-09"}
...


You can use to_date to convert the string field to the date field in the spark dataframe as follows:
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

data=gluecontext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="sample", table_name="table")
data_frame = data.toDF()

# convert the string field to the date field in the spark data frame
data_frame = data_frame.withColumn("date", to_date("date", "yyyy-MM-dd"))


thank you. if i may, one question along the same line, is there a way to generate a unique key , within spark dataframe , that can be used to generate unique ids or some sort of id that can be used as primary key , when this gets written to a rds table?

You can use monotonically_increasing_id but if you want it to be consecutive then you can use row_number.
